# Elvis operator troubleshoting

Tags: c#

I want to check if value is null in my `ctor`, if interface is null i want to throw an exception.

```
_someiInterface = someInterface.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

So i write this piece of code:

```
_someiInterface = someInterface?.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
    ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

Code above throws when `someInterface` is not null. When i dive into `elvis` operator explenation in ms docs it said, that methods on the right side executes when `someInterface` is not null.

My question is, why from code above it throws when `someInterface` is not null?

Comment: What exception is thrown, and what is its stack trace?

Comment: Could it be that sometimes `GetResult()` returns null?

Comment: `System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.` And stack trace from my constructor

Comment: That's your own code throwing because `GetResult()` returned `null`

Comment: If you intend to throw anyway, there's no point in using `?.`. Just check `someInterface` for null and throw if it's null

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos something like `someInterface ?? throw new...` will work in case of someInterface will be null?

Comment: Or an old-fashioned `if(someInterface==null) throw new ArgumentNullException();`. You don't have to put everything in a single line. In fact you *shouldn't* unless you get a real benefit

Comment: In this case using `?.` means you have no idea what produced that `null`. Was `someInterface` null? Or the result? Should you throw an `ArgumentNullException` when the argument *wasn't* null ?

Comment: `(someInterface ?? throw new ArgumentNullException()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`. This will only throw if `someInterface` is null, and not when the result is null. In case you really want to do it as a oneliner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_someiInterface = someInterface?.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
    ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

This is saying that if the expression `someInterface?.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` results in `null`, then throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

`someInterface?.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` can result in `null` if:

1. `someInterface` is `null`
2. `someInterface` is not `null`, and `someInterface.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` returns  `null`

Since you said that `someInterface` is not `null`, then logically the cause is that `someInterface.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` returns `null`.